# Gson, cursor.getString crashes the app when reading JSON Array of strings

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-sqlite, gson

I wrote a smaller test of code that is giving me trouble in my app. The opening and closing of the database is just from two activities in my app and I wanted it to be as close as possible. I keep getting

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY 
>        but was NUMBER at line 1 column 2 path $

and can't figure out why it is giving this error since it should just read an arraylist of strings. COLUMN_DATE is a string type.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayList dateAr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("01-02-2016", "08-02-2016", "15-02-2016", "15-07-2019"));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String dateString = gson.toJson(dateAr);

        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
        }.getType();

        SQLiteDatabaseHandler mDbHelper = new SQLiteDatabaseHandler(this);

        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_DATE, dateString);

        System.out.print(dateString);

        db.close();


        SQLiteDatabaseHandler mBBHelper = new SQLiteDatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase BB = mBBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + DataContract.DataEntry.TABLE_NAME;

        Cursor cursor = BB.rawQuery(query, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            dateAr = gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(0), type);
        }
            cursor.close();


            dateAr = gson.fromJson(dateString, type);


            System.out.print(dateAr);


    }
}
```

It is odd to me why the Type class works for decoding my BigDecimal arraylists but not for my date ones. I tried just getting the strings as the first answer suggested and while it works in the snippet it only picks up like the first digit of random parts of dates. Ex:

```
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            dateAr.add(cursor.getString(0));
            payAr = gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(1), DB);
            intAr = gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(2), DB);
            prinAr = gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(3), DB);
            balAr = gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(4), DB);
}
           cursor.close()
```

Also probably relevant, when I first put the Json versions of my arraylists into the database:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_DATE, dateString);
    values.put(DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_Pay, payString);
    values.put(DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_Int, intString);
    values.put(DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_Prin, prinString);
    values.put(DataContract.DataEntry.COLUMN_Bal, balString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had switched structures from an arraylist of calendars to an arraylist of strings and didn't realize that the old data was still in the database so it tried to read the calendars incorrectly. Originally I was also incorrectly reading calendar because I wasn't adhering to its class structure. Adding a refresh class did the trick:

```
public void refresh(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DataContract.DataEntry.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

I never wanted to store the data long term I just needed a way to pass lots of data beyond what intents could.